# Selenium : How to retrieve WebDriver's implicitWait time in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

It's convenient to set WebDriver's implicitWait time when webapp contains lots of dynamically loaded contents. But the global implicitWait time turns out to be too long sometimes, in which cases I wish to reduce it temporarily, and then restore it to its previous value. 
The problem is : How to retrieve the value of the webdriver's current implicitWait time?

Comment: I use the PageObjects Pattern for my webapp automation test designing. It's reasonable to reuse the WebDriver object across different pages. Even in the same one TestClass, many pages might be involved.  It's time-consuming to instantiate a WebDriver object for each method.

Comment: I've got a static WebDriver object `driver` in `Page` class, which is the base class of all Page Objects. I set the `implicitWait` time when `Page.driver` is instantiated（only once per test suite）, which happens before any pageobjects' instantiation.  Chances are that I need to check the immediate presentaion of some optional webelements to decide what to do, when I need to set implicitWait time to zero, and restore it later.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrapp to a method something like
 `Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expected time to wait for element here))` 
Introduce a FINAL value (eg. 45sec). Change ImplicitlyWait by the method - before FindElement is called - to any value and then go back to your FINAL one.
Note:After creation of driver default ImplicitlyWait is equal to 0sec at the very beginning.
But if I were you I would overload common FindElement/FindElements method and add there Explicitly wait. It would work like following:
1)Driver.FindElement(By something) <-- uses global ImplicitlyWait
2)Driver.FindElement(By something, 10) <-- uses Explicitly
It's much more flexible solution.

Comment: Any link supporting that its 0 sec?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/timeouts/implicit_wait